# Query to get Data by Date of different Fields

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to get data from a database using compare date(income,outcome date and another field) I'm using this format:

```
Form6.ADOTable1.Filter := 'student_name like '+QuotedStr(sEdit1.Text) +
       ' and income_date  >='''+date1+''' and income_date  <= '''+date2+'''+
       ' and outcome_date >='''+date1+''' and outcome_date <= '''+date2+'''';
```

when I run the program I get an error, I don't know why. Please help me.
**I am using Delphi 7**

Comment: pls, show us full code. What is `date1` and `date2` and wich format does it have?

Comment: tell us what is the error you are getting ? and also post a sample code to show what have you done so far.

Comment: Maybe date1 is later/greater than date2?

Comment: you probably need to add '%' to your quotedstr as wildcard ...like '+QuotedStr('%'+sEdit1.Text+'%') and...

Comment: "i get error" means nothing to anyone but you. Please edit your question to provide the error you're getting, including the **exact** error message. We can't see your screen (or the rest of your code) from here; we only know what you're telling us in your question. Thanks. :)

Comment: As a matter of fact, the particular piece of code you have posted here is missing one single quote character. It's at the end of your second line. It reads `+'''+`, but it should be `+''''+`. However, I'm sure you would have noticed that and the char's only missing in your question, not in your real code. For you do use syntax highlighting, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is not clear, you can try different approach to filter your records:
Add an TADOQuery component. Establish DB connection in connection properties. Then apply the following code to whatever event you used before:

```
With ADOQuery1 do 
begin
    close;
    sql.clear;
    sql.add('SELECT * FROM table 
             WHERE student_name like '+QuotedStr(sEdit1.Text)+' 
             AND income_date  >='+date1+'
             AND income_date  <='+date2+' 
             AND outcome_date >='+date1+' 
             AND outcome_date <='+date2);
    open;
end;

If you are using DBCommponents, Make sure you link them with ADOQury1 instead of ADOTable1.
```